# PHP asynchronous tasks - sending results to browser when ready

Tags: php, html, asynchronous, pthreads, gearman

In PHP, I want to run several independent tasks in parallel. Each task produces a result that I want to send back to the visitor's browser as the results are ready. The idea is to use load a page normally and then use HTML5 SSE (Server-sent events) to send data to the browser as it becomes available, while keeping the HTTP connection open with `keep-alive`. I do not just want to flush the output; I will be doing quite a few different tasks that are all perfect candidates for running in parallel, so I do not want to perform them synchronously.

My initial thought was to do multi-threading with the [pthreads extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php). I am not exactly sure how threads work with PHP; is the connection to the browser kept open for as long as I have a thread running, i.e. can I safely send data back to the browser from the threads? I think that pthreads is pretty stable, but I am not convinced that I should use it because it is experimental.

> pthreads was, and is, an experiment with pretty good results. Any of
>   its limitations or features may change at any time; that is the nature
>   of experimentation.

Then I remembered about Gearman, which allows me to use workers for my tasks. Background workers is what I need because I do not want my script execution to block while waiting for jobs to finish, as I want to run several jobs in parallel. This is no problem with Gearman, but I am quite unsure that I can send the results back to the Gearman client if I use background workers. As I understood, background workers will run in their own processes or contexts, so I guess this means that I cannot send data back to the browser from my background workers? I noticed that the [GearmanClient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.gearmanclient.php) provides a few methods for setting callbacks, but as far as I could read from my research, it seems as if these callbacks are only invoked with synchronous calls. Ideally, I would either want to send the results back directly from my background workers (I doubt it's possible), or have the background workers notify the client when it finishes, without having to probe Gearman for job statuses. A callback handler would be optimal, as I could then send data back from there.

I also considered using a messaging system (or memcached) such as ActiveMQ together with [ZendQueue](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.queue.adapters.html). The idea would be to send worker requests on a channel and then listen on a different channel for results. When a message is read from the result channel, the message is sent directly to the browser. The downside is that I would be doing additional work, such as mapping result messages to requests.

In the end, I am very much leaning towards the Gearman approach, but I am just not sure if it is possible to accomplish what I want. To sum up, I want to perform parallel tasks that take up to a few seconds each and send them back to the browser individually as the results are ready (by using HTML5 SSE).

Are my approaches possible? Do you have any other ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I certainly don't have the answer for you, but would be curious who did, and what it is!

Comment: I think a good solution would be to use Ajax if that's possible. If it is I'll write up an answer for you. I've never worked with Gearman, but maybe the following link can give you some ideas: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/108-Distributing-PHP-processing-with-Gearman.html

Comment: Have you read about RabbitMQ? Its an AMQP implementation. It could be useful for your case. Read the sixth example in the official here http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html (the example is java, but there are enough php example out there).

Comment: @Nick Unless I misunderstood what you meant, AJAX does not seem suitable for this. My hope is to be able to execute quite a few tasks in parallel, which would require just as many HTTP connections to the web server. The link you posted is quite useful for using Gearman in general, but unfortunately the Gearman client does not seem to be notified when the workers finish their work. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @Guumaster Not a bad idea, although I think RabbitMQ does not provide me with much that ActiveMQ does not (in the example you referenced anyways). But it's good to have a few choices! :-) Having thought a bit more about it, I don't see any reason why using a message queue would not work. I have a few challenges in mind, though, but in general the idea sounds credible. Thanks for the mentioning of RabbitMQ; I had not heard of that project before.

Comment: @Andy0708 Ah, I'm terribly sorry. I was sure the site was talking about that specifically, but on second read it did not. I'm probably not qualified to answer your question if Ajax is not an answer, because it probably means I do not understand your requirements well enough, haha.

Comment: @Andy0708 - out of curiosity, have you found the solution to your problem?

Comment: @N.B. I think I will go with an AJAX approach. I have like ~30 things that I wanted to process in parallel. What I think I will do is to group them and make an AJAX request for each group, and thus limit the number of connections. It's still an "ugly" approach, but as long as I only have a few connection, it's OK. The messaging approach seems better, but it is also a lot of work and complications of the production environment/tool stack to save a few light-weight HTTP requests. I think I will do a trade-off. The _groups_ are processed in parallel, which is not ideal, but good enough for now.

Comment: I've had a similar problem to you, after about 4 weeks of work I ended up with a software stack that does asynchronous task processing and so on (using pthreads plugin by Joe Watkins). I figured I'd ask whether you managed to solve the problem, so I can save time writing a lengthy answer in case you did :)

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the pthreads part.

As yet, persistent threads are not supported, so at the end of each request, all created contexts are destroyed (joined). Sending data directly from threads to the browser is likely a bad idea (and in some setups will cause a crash), the reason is that there's no control at the level of Zend over the output of apache or whatever sapi it is you are using, so pthreads makes no effort to hook up stdout's or any of that ... the idea should be to have the thread (or process) that accepted the connection deal with output to the client, using data from the threads it creates...

Persistent threads are a bit problematic, persistent objects are not really supported in PHP, the way mysqli etc provide persistent objects is different to the thing pthreads requires for persistent threads, firstly, their interface is always the same (ie, it implements mysqli), where pthreads are implemented in PHP by the user. Even if I were to work around that problem, I can envisage them being misunderstood very easily, my experiments with persistent threads continue, the documentation will be updated if or when I find a suitable implementation.